# Reducer "language" returned undefined during initialization - error with combineReducers

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-state

I have a problem with config for redux, I'm brand new in React and Redux, and redux isn't similar to vuex so I don't know yet how can I figure out this problem.
Let's go into my code then.

Little note: I'm sure that I have each import that i need, so let me show only code for clear view.

**index.jsx**

```
let store = createStore(reducers);
store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()));
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
, window.document.querySelector('#app-container'));
```

**.../store/reducer/index.js**

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
    language
});

export default reducers;
```

**.../store/reducer/language/languageFrom.js**

```
const languageFromReducer = (state = "", action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "SET_LANGUAGE":
            return state = action.payload; //I'm almost sure that this one is wrong O.o
    }
}

export default languageFromReducer;
```

**.../store/action/languageFrom.js**

```
export const setLanguage = (language) => {
    return {
        type: "SET_LANGUAGE",
        payload: language
    };
};
```

This is what I configured for redux, and I get only information about initial state which is undefined. I was looking for any discussion about it but I didn't find something what can clearly figured out my problem.

**The entire error log:**

```
Uncaught Error: Reducer "language" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null instead of undefined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reducer is missing the default switch case. As for the return syntax, you can just return `action.payload` directly. The returned value is passed to the reducer as `state` the next time it runs.

```
const languageFromReducer = (state = "", action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "SET_LANGUAGE":
            return action.payload; //I'm almost sure that this one is wrong O.o
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but tell me one thing (obviously if u can). If i just return the payload the state in whole application will be changed on this value from payload? What I mean about - If I return this payload then I want to just get this value in another component it will return me this payload value too?

Comment: When you use `connect` or `useSelector`, whenever state updates in the store, a the connected components re-render with the new values.

Comment: By the way, I'd suggest taking a look at the official Redux tutorial! https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts